# Auto refresh bot won't click on element

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, element

I'm trying to create a bot that auto refreshes and stops whenever the desired element is available to click/visible. I've made the refresh part and the bot stops when it sees the desired element, but I just can't figure out why it doesn't click on the element:/
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEBTz.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\selenium drivers\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("xxx")

driver.maximize_window()

click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="coiPage-1"]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]')
click.click()

while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="siteContainer"]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/form/button'))))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="siteContainer"]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/form/button').click()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### presence_of_element_located()

[*`presence_of_element_located()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) takes a *locator* as an argument but not an element.

So you need to change:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx'))))
```

as:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xxx")))
```

---

Ideally, to locate the ***clickable*** element and invoke *`click()`* on it, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xxx"))).click()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
```

Comment: Your solution worked, the bot will now click on the element its told and if the element isnt present it will refresh until. ty so much:)

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess you are using non-unique locator so that `driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx')` returns you a wrong element so that clicking on it does nothing.
   To fix this issue validate the `xxx` XPath locator you are using is unique.
2. Or maybe you trying to click on that element too early so that it gives you `ElementClickInterceptedException` or something similar.
   To give better answer we need to see your actual code, not `xxx` if it is possible, including the errors traceback.

Comment: ive updated it with log and changed the xxx to the xpath

Comment: I can't check uniqueness of your locator as well as anything else without seeing your page with browser devtools etc.